# Assign progressive number if a condition is met - R

Tags: r, sequence

How do I assign progressive numbers to a column every time a given condition is met in another one? Given this data:

```
a <- data.frame(var = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 4, 5, 6, 1, 7, 1, 1))
```

I would like to construct a column that is progressively augmented by 1 every time var == 1 and returns NAs for the rest. The new column should then be filled with:

```
1, NA, NA, 2, NA, NA, NA, 3, NA, 4, 5
```

I thought about ifelse but I didn't manage to make it work. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can use `ifelse` and `cumsum`:

```
a$newvar <- ifelse(a$var==1, cumsum(a$var==1), NA)
   var newvar
1    1      1
2    0     NA
3    0     NA
4    1      2
5    4     NA
6    5     NA
7    6     NA
8    1      3
9    7     NA
10   1      4
11   1      5
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd just like to add one more thing for a general case in which if you want to do the same thing for 4 or 5 or any thing else

```
a <- data.frame(var = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 4, 5, 6, 1, 7, 1, 1))

a$New <- ifelse(a$var == 1,1,NA)
a$New[!is.na(a$New)] <- cumsum(a$New[!is.na(a$New)])
```

Output:

```
> print(a)
   var New
1    1   1
2    0  NA
3    0  NA
4    1   2
5    4  NA
6    5  NA
7    6  NA
8    1   3
9    7  NA
10   1   4
11   1   5
```

Comment: Or just `a$New <- NA ; a$New[a$var == 1] <- cumsum(a$var[a$var == 1])`

Comment: What if he wants to count var = 0 ? or any other number ?

Comment: In that case your New var will be 0 ; Output : [1] NA  0  0 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ; Desired output : [1] NA  1  2 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA

Comment: I have proposed this solution assuming that he wants a count of that particular variable, If the OP wants only the cumulative sum then ytk's answer is good enough

Comment: Good point. Then, `a$New <- NA ; a$New[a$var == 0] <- seq_len(sum(a$var == 0))` would be better perhaps

Answer (score 0):

We can also do this with a variation of `cumsum`

```
a$newVar <- with(a, cumsum(var ==1) * NA^(var!=1))
a$newVar
#[1]  1 NA NA  2 NA NA NA  3 NA  4  5
```

---

Or using `data.table`, we convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(a)`), specify the logical condition in 'i' (`var == 1`), and assign (`:=` it is efficient as it assigns in place) the `cumsum` of 'var' to 'newvar'.  By default, the other elements in 'newvar' that do not correspond to the logical condition will be filled by NA.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(a)[var==1, newvar := cumsum(var)]
a
#    var newvar
# 1:   1      1
# 2:   0     NA
# 3:   0     NA
# 4:   1      2
# 5:   4     NA
# 6:   5     NA
# 7:   6     NA
# 8:   1      3
# 9:   7     NA
#10:   1      4
#11:   1      5
```

Or instead of `cumsum` we can use the sequence of rows

```
setDT(a)[var==1, newvar := seq_len(.N)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another base R option, but without `cumsum`

```
> transform(a, newvar = replace(NA*var, var==1, seq(sum(var==1))))
   var newvar
1    1      1
2    0     NA
3    0     NA
4    1      2
5    4     NA
6    5     NA
7    6     NA
8    1      3
9    7     NA
10   1      4
11   1      5
```